# Run svn update and ant build in parallel

Tags: bash, svn, parallel-processing, ant

I have a bunch of svn projects that I want to update and build with ant. At the moment I have a sequential approach:

```
find /opt/src/ -path "*/trunk/build.xml" -execdir svn update $(dirname {}) \; -exec ant -f {} \;
```

Now I want to run the ant build in parallel (or background) so that the find command can proceed without being blocked by the ant call. I already read about forking in bash with '&' but could not figure out how to use it correctly in my case.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a for loop, starting each iteration in the background

```
for f in $(find /opt/src/ -path "*/trunk/build.xml") do
...
...
done &
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i created this script: 

´for f in $(find /opt/src/ -path "*/trunk/build.xml"); do
svn update $(dirname $f)
ant -f $f
done &´

Unfortunately I cant see any improvement on the execution time, my expectation was that the cpu will be more busy due to parallel compilation with ant. But it seems not to happen.

Comment: If my suggestion helped you then please accept it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a while of fiddle around, I got this solution:

```
for f in $(find /opt/src/ -path "*/trunk/build.xml"); do 
svn update $(dirname $f); 
konsole --noclose --nofork -e ``ant -f $f`` &; 
done
```

The svn updates run serially and the ant builds in parallel. This means, as soon as the svn update of a certain directory completes an ant build will be started in an separate console(here terminal app of kde) window.
Starting to many svn updates in parallel caused network errors within my environment, so I changed the behavior as described above.